# Spring: how pass values to constructor from properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have a `MongoService` class as

```
public class MongoService {

    private final Mongo mongo;
    private final String database;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoService.class);

    public MongoService(@Nonnull final String host, final int port, @Nonnull final String db) throws UnknownHostException {
        mongo = new Mongo(host, port);
        database = db;
    }

    public void putDocument(@Nonnull final DBObject document) {
        LOGGER.info("inserting document - " + document.toString());
        mongo.getDB(database).getCollection(getCollectionName(document)).insert(document, WriteConcern.SAFE);
    }

    public void putDocuments(@Nonnull final List<DBObject> documents) {
        for (final DBObject document : documents) {
            putDocument(document);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to inject the value of `host, port, db` into **constructor** from a external properties file
**/storage/local.properties**

```
### === MongoDB interaction === ###
host=127.0.0.1
port=27017
database=contract
```

My Spring wireup file looks as follows
**wireup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

    <util:properties id="mongoProperties" location="file:///storage//local.properties" />

    <bean id="mongoService" class="com.business.persist.MongoService">
        // TODO
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Question**

How can I pass the value of `host, port, db` from `local.properties` file and pass it to the following constructor?

```
public MongoService(@Nonnull final String host, final int port, @Nonnull final String db) throws UnknownHostException {
        mongo = new Mongo(host, port);
        database = db;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of importing your properties file using the util:properties tag, you want to import it using the context:property-placeholder.  The util version simply imports the file as a Properties object, rather than exposing the property values to your configuration.  So your setup would be something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///storage//local.properties"/>
```

Then when you are wiring up your MongoService, you can use the property names in your constructor config, such as

```
<bean id="mongoService" class="com.business.persist.MongoService">
    <constructor-arg value="${host}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${port}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${database}"/>
</bean>
```

See [the spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) for more details.
On a side note I would consider giving a more descriptive name to each of the properties to avoid collision with other properties that might be defined in your application.

Answer (score 16):

*Mike* and *Sean* gave perfectly adequate answers. **Here is one addition**: once your `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` is set up correctly, consider the nowadays widely used `@Value` annotation for injecting those properties into the constructor:

```
public class MongoService {

  ..

  @Autowired
  public MongoService(@Value("${host}") final String host, @Value("${port}") final int port, @Value("${db}") @Nonnull final String db) throws UnknownHostException {
      mongo = new Mongo(host, port);
      database = db;
  }

..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

define a property placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:path/to/your.properties"/>
```

and now use the properties:

```
<bean id="mongoService" class="com.business.persist.MongoService">
    <constructor-arg value="${property.foo}" />
    <constructor-arg value="${property.bar}" />
</bean>
```

See: [4.8.2.1 Example: the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

Answer (score 5):

To read Spring `application.properties` in constructor one could use the following example:

```
// File: sample/Message.groovy

package sample
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*
import org.springframework.stereotype.*

@Component
class Message {

    final String text

    // Use @Autowired to get @Value to work.
    @Autowired
    Message(
        // Refer to configuration property
        // app.text to set value for
        // constructor argument text.
        @Value('${app.text}') final String text) {
        this.text = text
    }
}
```

Source: [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-sweets-using-value#:%7E:text=In%20Spring%20we%20can%20use,on%20the%20constructor%20as%20well.)

Comment: application.properites sets property value like this app.text=somevalue

Comment: it's groovy, so in Java it's `@Value("${app.text}")`